# AOP Pointcut expression for methods belonging to classes in various subpackages

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

Context: I am running a Spring service that deals with interaction with external partners and vendors. I'm implementing a monitoring aspect to keep track of the QPS as well as other performance metrics for each of these external APIs.

They are implemented in a way where there is a parent class with an abstract protected `execute()` method that is being implemented for each vendor. (i.e. each vendor has its own class).

The directory is organized as such:

com.org.biz.vendor.impl.{vendor}.{vendorServiceProviderClass}

i.e.

- com/org/biz/service/vendor/impl/vendorA/VendorAServiceProvider
- com/org/biz/service/vendor/impl/vendorB/VendorBServiceProvider

where each Provider class overrides the `execute()` method. They are all named with a -Provider suffix.

I have tried to apply the Pointcut as follows:

```
@Pointcut("execution(protected * com.org.biz.service.vendor.impl..*Provider.doExecute(..))")
    public void monitoringPointCut() {
    }

    @Around("monitoringPointCut()")
    public Object writeToMetrics(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        // compute metrics and write to logs
    }
```

I have also tried some other variants but I can't seem to get the method intercepted regardless of which vendor implementation I tried to trigger. I'm not sure if it's because it is an overriden method, or if it's because its protected.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you not making a simple problem complicated? Why do you not use a pointcut intercepting the method based on the superclass, intercepting all overriding classes? Would that not suit your needs better and be more reliable than focusing on naming rules? Based on your reply, I can suggest a solution. But I need your feedback first.

Comment: hi @kriegaex, thanks for your response. yes, i realized that intercepting the method from the superclass would be sufficient. previously i had the misconception that I had to be intercepting concrete methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (I invented a class and package name for the abstract base class):

```java
execution(* com.org.biz.service.base.AbstractProvider+.doExecute(..))
```

The `+` means "include subclasses".

You could also write it like this:

```java
within(com.org.biz.service.base.AbstractProvider+) && execution(* doExecute(..))
```

Now the subclass names and their package names do not matter anymore, because you are focusing on inheritance rather than naming.